# IOS: CHROME: keyboard is not pushing view up when it opens

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, google-chrome

Test Device: iphone 6 IOS 12.0.1 Chrome: 72.0.3

When the keyboard opens is not pushing the view up, instead it covers part of the screen. I have an input at the bottom of the page (is a chat, so is the input at the bottom of it) which is overlap by the keyboard. I try testing this bug using Browserstack, but in there works fine, so I guess is a version issue. Is there a known bug or a way to force the keyboard to push the view up?

Example is Browserstack
[image]

Example in Test Device:
[image]

Comment: This sounds more like a bug with the chrome app, not sure there is anything we can help you with here?

Comment: Thanks @Scriptable, yes I am afraid it is probably a bug. I wrote the question with the hope that there may be a work around or a way to force that view push upwards. Or even to find out if it is a recurrent error so I can label it a a bug of the browser. I have search everywhere for an answer but have fail to find something related to this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue (version: 71.0.3578.89). I suspect it is a bug since last Chrome update 28. January. If any info is found, please do update here, and so will I:) All the best:)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem (iOS with Chrome not pushing the keyboard up so items were covered by it) with our website and it looks like hard resetting our iPhone did the trick for us. Hope it helps you guys too :)

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
var devicePlatform = cordova.platformId;
if (devicePlatform == "android" || devicePlatform == "iOS" || devicePlatform == "ios") {
    /* cache dom references */ 
    var $body = $('body'); 

    /* bind events */
    $(document)
    .on('focus', 'input', function() {
        $body.addClass('fixfixed');
    })
    .on('blur', 'input', function() {
            $body.removeClass('fixfixed');
    })
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.urClass { position: fixed;} .fixfixed .urClass { position: static; }
```